# Banner is too small on mobile device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, adaptive-design

At some point I know I need to bite the bullet and do some serious reading on responsive and adaptive design, but I was hoping there was a really simple way to address this issue.

I have the following web page, shown here in my desktop browser.

[image]

And here is the same page on my cell phone.

[image]

Although it's probably hard to tell here, the banner is too small when viewed on my cell phone.

Ideally, I would like to have it so:

- The width of the page content (and the corresponding width of my `<footer>` element, which has a top border) does not take up the entire width of the browser when it's full screen on the desktop, but does take up the entire width of my cell phone.
- The banner would never be bigger than the pixel width of the image on my desktop, but would take up the entire width of my small cell phone.

Is there any simplified approach to this?

Comment: have you heard of [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)?

Comment: Make the image the dimensions you want it to be on mobile, then use media queries to restrict the width on desktop.

Comment: @cocoa: Yes, I have heard of media queries, and I get the basic idea. But I'm new to them and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to a really simple approach to do this on a very simple site. I guess I could make the width of stuff 100% when the device is small, and say 60% when it's larger. Not sure yet if that's the simplest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `media-queries` to handle style changes based on the viewport. For instance, you can do something like:

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kxgxkc8d/1/)

```
/* Desktop Styles here*/
footer {
  background: blue;
  width: 500px;
}
.banner > img {
  width: 300px;
}

/* When the screen is smaller than 560px, specify what properties you wan to change. */
@media only screen and (max-width: 560px) {
  footer {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .banner > img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the head start. Going to play with this a little.

Comment: Just added a fiddle for the example.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from media queries which you should seriously look into for serious responsiveness, you will also need to adjust the viewport meta tag in your header.
Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to your `<head>` tag to instruct the phone browser not to attempt to display the page as in a zoomed-out state.
So, for instance:

```
...
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
        <title>Hooray Banana</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="This page is a placeholder for future content.">
        <meta name="description" content="sc web group">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
...
```

Then F12 and view in a phone emulation mode or check on your phone directly.

Comment: Yes, this step was necessary. I still need to do more research as to why, but I understand it is scaling down otherwise for some unknown reason.

Comment: Hi @JonathanWood, this is not for unknown reasons. Your phone's browser by default tries to show the whole page, if you don't specify the viewport meta tag. If you set it (to initial-scale of 1, for example), then it tell s the browser not to zoom out initially. You can also set "maximum-scale=1" to tell the browser not to zoom in when double-tapped. Essentially:
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

See here for more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
I hope you find my post helpful. Any questions, please do ask.

Comment: But it is unknown to me why it has to scale down to show the whole page. Because we all know by now that the page will fit just fine at scale set to 1.

Comment: @JonathanWood, without the  meta tag and initial scale of 1, the browser attempts to show the whole webpage so it assumes an initial scale lower than 1 (let's say 0.5 for argument's sake). The reason is, it tries to behave like a desktop browser and show the page as it would show on a desktop browser. Why? Because phone browsers came to existence after desktops. By setting the meta tag and the appropriate value, you are telling the phone browser to behave like a phone browser and display the page as it would show on a phone, not a desktop.

Comment: To try and understand this a bit more, try changing the initial scale value - set it to 0.5 and see how it looks on your phone, then change it to 1 and then to 2.